# Turn if-else-if statement into switch statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am having trouble turning this block of code from an if else statement to a switch statement. The function is called in the html doc. Can anyone give me some pointers?

function calcu(calcValue) {

```
if (calcValue == '1')
{
  calc.output.value += '1';
}
else if (calcValue == '2')
{
  calc.output.value += '2';
}
else if (calcValue == '3')
{
  calc.output.value += '3';
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your attempt at making the switch and let us know what exact issue it has?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch and what takendarkk said. Give it a go and let us know what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (calcValue == '1')
{
  calc.output.value += '1';
}
else if (calcValue == '2')
{
  calc.output.value += '2';
}
else if (calcValue == '3')
{
  calc.output.value += '3';
}
```

**To:**

```js
const switchStatement = () =>{
    let calcValue = 1;
    switch(calcValue){
        case "1": 
            calc.output.value += '1';
            break;
        case "2": 
            calc.output.value += '2';
            break;
        case "3": 
            calc.output.value += '3';
            break;
        default: 
            calc.output.value += '0';
    }
    return calcValue
}

// Calling Function
console.log(switchStatement())
```

Answer (score -1):

basically and `if` can be turned into a `switch` following this:

```
if(something === match1){
    output = desirecOutput1;
}else if(something ==== match2){
    output = desiredOutput2;
}
....
....
....
else if(something === matchN){
    output = desiredOutputN;
}else{
    output = desiredOutputDefault;
}
```

to:

```
switch(something){
    case match1:
        output = desirecOutput1;
        break;
    case match2:
        output = desiredOutput2;
        break;
    ....
    ....
    case matchN:
        output = desiredOutputN;
        break;
    default:
        output = desiredOutputDefault;
        break;
}
```

so basically on your code:

```
if (calcValue == '1')
{
  calc.output.value += '1';
}
else if (calcValue == '2')
{
  calc.output.value += '2';
}
else if (calcValue == '3')
{
  calc.output.value += '3';
}
```

it would be:

```
switch (calcValue) {
  case '1':
    calc.output.value += '1';
    break;
  case '2':
    calc.output.value += '2';
    break;
  case '3':
    calc.output.value += '3';
    break;
  default:
    calc.output.value += '0';
}
```